# Get the input of a DIV row with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding div dynamically. Please see the below image. When I'm clicking on Update button I need to get current row cell values. How can i achieved that through jQuery or JavaScript ? I tried this way var InputVal = $(this).closest('.row');

```
<div class="Row">
            <input type="hidden" id="hid_2167" value="200">
            <div class="Cell2">eztest</div>
            <div class="Cell1" id="edit_2167_8053" style="display: table-cell;">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The must not be blank" data-val-length-max="20" id="DeviceMappingList_12__FirstName" name="DeviceMappingList[12].FirstName" type="text" value="j"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="disp_2167_8053" style="display: none;">
                j
            </div>
            <div class="Cell1" id="edit_2167_8053" style="display: table-cell;">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field LastName must be a string with a maximum length of 20." data-val-length-max="20" id="DeviceMappingList_12__LastName" name="DeviceMappingList[12].LastName" type="text" value="d"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="disp_2167_8053" style="display: none;">
                d
            </div>
            <div class="Cell1" id="edit_2167_8053" style="display: table-cell;">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Email must be a string with a maximum length of 30." data-val-length-max="30" id="DeviceMappingList_12__Email" name="DeviceMappingList[12].Email" type="text" value="jd"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="disp_2167_8053" style="display: none;">
                jd
            </div>
            <div class="Cell1" id="edit_2167_8053" style="display: table-cell;"><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field MobileNumber must be a string with a maximum length of 20." data-val-length-max="20" id="DeviceMappingList_12__MobileNumber" name="DeviceMappingList[12].MobileNumber" type="text" value="085"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="disp_2167_8053" style="display: none;">
                085
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                Alan
                <input id="DeviceMappingList_12__UserName" name="DeviceMappingList[12].UserName" type="hidden" value="Alan">

            </div>
            <div class="Cell1" id="edit_2167_8053" style="display: table-cell;"><input altid="hid_2167" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required." id="DeviceMappingList_12__IsActive" name="DeviceMappingList[12].IsActive" onclick="return checkrows(this)" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="DeviceMappingList[12].IsActive" type="hidden" value="false"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="disp_2167_8053" style="background-color: lightgreen; display: none;">
                <a href="#" onclick="changeDeviceStatus(2167,8053,'True','eztest')">Deactivate</a>
            </div>
                        
            <div class="Cell2">21/11/2019 09:49:12</div>
            <div class="Cell2">9DF2573B-DEF7-455C-9625-517DBED8556F</div>
            <div class="Cell2">2.3.23</div>
            <div class="Cell2">13.3.1</div>
            <div class="Cell2">iPad (5th Gen) (Wi-F</div>

            <input style="display:none" type="checkbox" name="chkdeviceId" id="chkdeviceId" chkid="chk_2167_8053" value="8053">
            <input style="display:none" type="checkbox" name="chkcompanyId" id="chkcompanyId" chkid="chk_2167_8053" value="2167">
            <div class="Cell3">
                <a href="" id="aedit" onclick="return editDeviceDetails(this,2167,8053)">cancel</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="#" style="display: block;" id="update_2167_8053" onclick="updatedevicedetails(2167,8053,eztest,j,d,jd,085 )">Update</a>&nbsp;
                <a href="" id="adelete" onclick="return deleteDevice(this,2167,8053,'eztest','iPad (5th Gen) (Wi-F')">delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I'm trying different way like dynamic value pass but When i'm changing any text value that i could not catch. Thanks ! onclick="updatedevicedetails(2167,8053,eztest,j,d,jd,085 )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this code and resolved. Thank you !

```
var row = $(this).closest('.Row');
  console.log(row.find('[id*=__FirstName]').val());
  console.log(row.find('[id*=__LastName]').val());
  console.log(row.find('[id*=__Email]').val());
```

Comment: Why do you mix `$=` and `*=` when there is no need to? You should understand what code means before using it. Here `$=` would suffice. If you don't know the difference, or what it does I urge you to have a look at the [MDN Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) page.